# LibGDX Android Studio, Intent can't be used in Core Directory

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I generated a LibGDX project, its a small game that i want to create. When i started Android studio i pressed import project and i chosed the LibGDX created directory.

so Android Studio created everything for me. It created 3 main Directories.
Android directory, Core directory, and Desktop directory.
in Android directory i have my Assets, and in the Core directory i have all my animations and java classes.

here is the issue:

the classes on the Core directory can't use Intent. Instead i have created a gameStateManager to be able to change between java classes in the Core directory.

The problem arrises when i have an int Score in Java Class A that i want to use in Java Class B. For the moment i can only Start Java class B from Java Class A using gameStateManager Class. But i cant add additional informations that i can do with Intents, such as Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra.

When i copy the java Classes in Core directory and paste it in Android directory i can use Intent. But it messes up my whole project so i don't want to do that.

what can i use in the Core directory classes to be able to share information with other classes in same directory.

I have tried using Getter, but it doesnt work good because in Java class B i have to write private A a = new A;
 int score = A.getScore();
And since i wrote private A a = new A;
that int score will always be 0.

so how do i solve this.

```
public abstract class State {
protected OrthographicCamera cam;
protected Vector3 mouse;
protected GameStateManager gsm;

protected State(GameStateManager gsm) {
    this.gsm = gsm;
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    mouse = new Vector3();
}

protected abstract void handleInput();

public abstract void update(float var1);

public abstract void render(SpriteBatch var1);

public abstract void dispose();
```

}

```
public class GameStateManager {
private Stack<State> states = new Stack();

public GameStateManager() {
}

public void push(State state) {
    states.push(state);
}

public void pop() {
    states.pop();

}

public void set(State state) {
    states.pop();
    states.push(state);
}

public void Update(float dt) {
    states.peek().update(dt);
}

public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    states.peek().render(sb);
}
```

}

```
public class A extends State {

private int score;





private Music collisionSound;
private Array<Box> boxes;
private Array<Coin> coins;

public A(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);

if(player.wins()) {
            coinSound.play();
            score++;

        if(player.loses()) {
            collisionSound.play();


            gsm.set(new B(gsm));

        }
  public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
public class B extends State {
private Texture background;
private Texture scoreBoard;
private Texture replayButton;
private BitmapFont scoreFont;
private A a = new A(gsm);
private int score;
private String empty = "";



public B(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);

    cam.setToOrtho(false, 240, 400);
    background = new Texture("bg.png");
    scoreBoard = new Texture("GAME_Score_Board.png");
    replayButton = new Texture("GAME_Score_Replay.png");
    scoreFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("ScoreFont.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("ScoreFont_0.png"), false);
    scoreFont.getData().setScale(0.5F);
    scoreFont.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    score = A.getScore();

    System.out.println("score " + score);

}



public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(this.cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(background, 0, 0);
    sb.draw(scoreBoard, 0, 100);
    scoreFont.draw(sb, empty+score, 165, 240);
    sb.end();
}
```

}

Comment: Any help please

Comment: Create a class that holds the values of variables that need to be accessed by multiple "States". Pass an instance of this object to the constructors of your various states.

Comment: thats just confusing, how is that going to help me.

Comment: could you please show

Comment: How long have you been using Java? From your code, you seem to understand abstract classes and generics, so how can you not understand a far more basic concept like I just described?

Comment: should i create    class C who got getter and setter for score int. and from class A, I call the setter method in class C and then in class B i call the getter method. because that didn't work either. the score still turns 0.

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple variables to pass from A to B. Otherwise, you can just pass your int score to the B constructor.

Comment: Thanks, i dont know why i couldn't figure that out myself. I used constructor in class B. But i still dont understand why class C getter turns 0 in class B after using setter from class A.

Comment: I don't know without seeing your code. I do see above that your B has a reference to a newly generated A which is not the same A that generated your B. So of course anything you do in your original A will not be reflected in B's reference to some other A.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood everything well, but let me try to explain.

First, all the assets (images, animations, sounds...) you must store in Android project. And for desktop, when you edit run configuration there is a field where you can/should set path to the assets so they will be available for desktop project too.

Second, Intent is Android class, so it's accessible only from Android project. Core project is common for all platforms so it can't use some platform specific classes. All common code you should keep in Core project and only some platform specific tweaks you should do in platform specific projects (Android, Desktop...).

So stick to the original project setup, work in your Core project and do not copy Core classes to Android or similar things.

Comment: I Understand that, and I have it as you said. But how do i acces the score in Java class A, in Java Class B, so that i can render it in Java Class B

Comment: Why does the score gets 0 in java class B when i use the getter.